# Pandas drop duplicates if reverse is present between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with 2 columns like the following...

```
InteractorA InteractorB
AGAP028204  AGAP005846
AGAP028204  AGAP003428
AGAP028200  AGAP011124
AGAP028200  AGAP004335
AGAP028200  AGAP011356
AGAP028194  AGAP008414
```

I'm using Pandas and I want to drop rows which are present twice but simply reversed like the following... from this...

```
InteractorA InteractorB
AGAP002741  AGAP008026
AGAP008026  AGAP002741
```

To this...

```
InteractorA InteractorB
AGAP002741  AGAP008026
```

As they are for all intents and purposes the same thing.

Is there a built in method to handle this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ended up making a hacky script which iterates over the rows and the necessary pieces of data and checks whether the concatenate appears or if its reverse appears and drops row indexes as appropriate.

```
import pandas as pd

checklist = []
indexes_to_drop = []

interactions = pd.read_csv('original_interactions.txt', delimiter = '\t')

for index, row in interactions.iterrows():
    check_string = row['InteractorA'] + row['InteractorB']
    check_string_rev = row['InteractorB'] + row['InteractorA']
    if (check_string or check_string_rev) in checklist:
        indexes_to_drop.append(index)
    else:
        pass
    checklist.append(check_string)
    checklist.append(check_string_rev)

no_dups = interactions.drop(interactions.index[indexes_to_drop])

print no_dups.shape

no_dups.to_csv('no_duplicates.txt',sep='\t',index = False)
```

---

**2017 EDIT**: a few years on, with a bit more experience, this is a much more elegant solution for anyone looking for something similar:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
  InteractorA InteractorB
0  AGAP028204  AGAP005846
1  AGAP028204  AGAP003428
2  AGAP028200  AGAP011124
3  AGAP028200  AGAP004335
4  AGAP028200  AGAP011356
5  AGAP028194  AGAP008414
6  AGAP002741  AGAP008026
7  AGAP008026  AGAP002741

In [18]: df['check_string'] = df.apply(lambda row: ''.join(sorted([row['InteractorA'], row['InteractorB']])), axis=1)

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
  InteractorA InteractorB          check_string
0  AGAP028204  AGAP005846  AGAP005846AGAP028204
1  AGAP028204  AGAP003428  AGAP003428AGAP028204
2  AGAP028200  AGAP011124  AGAP011124AGAP028200
3  AGAP028200  AGAP004335  AGAP004335AGAP028200
4  AGAP028200  AGAP011356  AGAP011356AGAP028200
5  AGAP028194  AGAP008414  AGAP008414AGAP028194
6  AGAP002741  AGAP008026  AGAP002741AGAP008026
7  AGAP008026  AGAP002741  AGAP002741AGAP008026

In [20]: df.drop_duplicates('check_string')
Out[20]:
  InteractorA InteractorB          check_string
0  AGAP028204  AGAP005846  AGAP005846AGAP028204
1  AGAP028204  AGAP003428  AGAP003428AGAP028204
2  AGAP028200  AGAP011124  AGAP011124AGAP028200
3  AGAP028200  AGAP004335  AGAP004335AGAP028200
4  AGAP028200  AGAP011356  AGAP011356AGAP028200
5  AGAP028194  AGAP008414  AGAP008414AGAP028194
6  AGAP002741  AGAP008026  AGAP002741AGAP008026
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the cleanest solution I've managed to make work for my own purposes.

Create a column that has each row combined in a sorted list

```
df['sorted_row'] = [sorted([a,b]) for a,b in zip(df.InteractorA, df.InteractorB)]
```

Can't drop duplicates on a list so that column should be a string

```
df['sorted_row'] = df['sorted_row'].astype(str)
```

Drop Duplicates

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['sorted_row'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would work:

```
In [37]:
import pandas as pd
import io
temp = """InteractorA InteractorB
AGAP028204  AGAP005846
AGAP028204  AGAP003428
AGAP028200  AGAP011124
AGAP028200  AGAP004335
AGAP028200  AGAP011356
AGAP028194  AGAP008414
AGAP002741  AGAP008026
AGAP008026  AGAP002741"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\s+')
df
Out[37]:
  InteractorA InteractorB
0  AGAP028204  AGAP005846
1  AGAP028204  AGAP003428
2  AGAP028200  AGAP011124
3  AGAP028200  AGAP004335
4  AGAP028200  AGAP011356
5  AGAP028194  AGAP008414
6  AGAP002741  AGAP008026
7  AGAP008026  AGAP002741
```

So I downloaded your data and misunderstood what you wanted so the following will now work:

```
# first get the values that are unique
In [72]:
df1 = df[~df.InteractorA.isin(df.InteractorB)]
df1.shape
Out[72]:
(2386, 2)
```

Now we want to get the duplicated rows but take the first value:

```
In [74]:

df2 = df[df.InteractorA.isin(df.InteractorB)]
df2 = df2.groupby('InteractorA').first().reset_index()
df2.shape
Out[74]:
(3074, 2)
```

now concat the 2 dataframes:

```
In [75]:

merged = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
merged.shape
Out[75]:
(5460, 2)
```

I think this is now correct.

Comment: This seems to get rid of some of them but not all, for example I still have `AGAP007031  AGAP010265` and `AGAP010265 AGAP007031` present in my dataset..

Comment: Still works for me, can you post more data so I can understand where this fails

Comment: Sure the dataset is here - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6037105/interactions_unique.txt

Comment: I see your problem, what you then have is duplicate rows far apart on row which is different at row 11672 and 21781, so you want to filter not succesive rows but any rows where values in InteractorA exist also in InteractorB is that correct?

Comment: @BML91 I misunderstood what you initially wanted so I've updated my answer, I get 2386 rows, is that correct?

Comment: @BML91 just realised this is not quite right, this will remove all dplicates rather than leave one behind, will have another think

Answer (score 0):

Was looking to solve a similar problem today. The answer by A.Kot put me in the right direction. Below is a working example. Copied the data preparation from the answer by EdChum.

````
import io
temp = """InteractorA InteractorB
AGAP028204  AGAP005846
AGAP028204  AGAP003428
AGAP028200  AGAP011124
AGAP028200  AGAP004335
AGAP028200  AGAP011356
AGAP028194  AGAP008414
AGAP002741  AGAP008026
AGAP008026  AGAP002741"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\s+')

# One liner to drop the duplicates
df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: set(x[['InteractorA', 'InteractorB']]), axis=1).drop_duplicates().index]```
````